# Java Regular expression for replacing specific strings

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace numbers in a string if it is more than 3 digits (Phone numbers should be replaced) and it should not replace the number if it is followed by $ and if the number has decimal points. I used the below expression.

> "\d{3,}+(?!\$/\.)"

Issues I face are , it is replacing numbers that are more than ten digits as i want to replace some numbers which are some ID's with more than 10 digits. Also if a number has more than 3 digits after the decimal , those numbers are also getting replaced. I dont want a number to be replaced if it has decimal points. can some body help?

For Eg, say a number string "3452678916381914". Actually it has to be replaced. But the above regex not replacing that. For numbers like $1234,45.567 - those numbers shouldn't be replaced. But above regex replacing 45.567

Comment: Give some example input/output.

Comment: I do not get the more-than-10-digit bit. So, you need to match int values that are 4-9 in length, and not followed with `$`? Try [`(?<!\.)\b\d{4,9}+\b(?!\$|\.\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/0X2Y3j/2).

Comment: `(?<![\.\$])\d{3,}(?![\.\$])` ?

Comment: For Eg, say a number string "3452678916381914". Actually it has to be replaced. But the above regex not replacing that. For numbers like $1234,45.567 - those numbers shouldn't be replaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) regex, 1st assert start word boundary is not precede by a `$` or `.`, then assert end word boundary is not follow by a `$` or `.`

It works for both example you provided, you might need to tweak a little bit to handle some corner case

```
(?<![\$\.])\b\d{3,}\b(?![\$\.])
```

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8nOhCT/1), it match the first 2 but not the rest

```
3452678916381914 # match
1234 56789       # match
$1234,45.567
$1234
12.345
12345.6678
123$
```

Comment: Thanks it worked . But still it fails in 2 cases. Actually I will have a text string . For Eg this is a test message 12345678.only for test cost 123$.   Here number - 12345678 has to be replaced and 123$ should not be replaced.

Comment: For my case, number before and after $ should not be replaced

Comment: i see, i didn't expect your string will have `$` behind, updated to assert number not follow by either `.` or `$`

Comment: Thanks alot.. I need to handle one more case . Eg test1234566 means numbers should be masked , result should be test#

Comment: assume test is a keyword to match, use `(?<=test)(\d+)` to match digit after test, replace with `#`, you gotta run this before solution above

Comment: Not only test any alphabetical characters

Comment: didn't get you right, what you mean by Not only test any alphabetical characters ???

Comment: For Eg ID1223456, SSN3456678,etc . Insuch cases also those numbers should be replaced. I tried as suggested by u..but it didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130093/discussion-between-skycc-and-hemsush).